# Automatically reconnect Openswan/IPSec VPN and disallow intermittent traffic?

Tags: bash, debian, ipsec

I am trying to connect two Debian machines running an Openswan/IPSec tunnel. Also, I want to disallow any traffic when the tunnel goes down. For that purpose I wrote a script the fiddles with routes and pings the the server's private IP to make sure the tunnel is up ([bash script](http://pastebin.com/PY1W6FKj)).

Thing is, that script is pretty ugly and doesn't work flawless. I was hoping there is a built-in way to maintain and automatically re-establish a VPN connection and to disallow traffic meanwhile.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If they are linux boxes, just add iptables rules.  Add rules required to permit the VPN, add rules to permit routing across the VPN then drop everything else.  As for making sure your VPN stays up and stable, I would look at using something like [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to monitor VPN connectivity, and issue the restart commands as required.

Comment: +1 for monit, I'll definitely have a look into it :)

Comment: As far as I know, if the routes are configured in OpenSWAN properly, it doesn't allow the traffic to go out except over the tunnel so long as you use the correct `auto=` options.